# About uitextfield on table cell

Tags: iphone, textfield, tablecell

I am making a app in this app i am using uitextfield on table cell.
I have made custom tablecell and declared a label and a textfield and I can see textfield on every tablecell but now i want that if I edit a taxtfield then changes will show all the textfield ......

If still there is something which is not clear then Please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after finishing text edit call `[tableView reload]` to load the table with new text what you have edited.

Answer (score 1):

After you have done the editing i.e. in

**TextFieldEndEditing method**(a delegate of textfield) call the method

```
[tableview reloadData]
```

which will reload the table and update your label and textfield inside cells to the set value.

**hAPPY iCODING...**